# Using Async With waterfall and Recursion in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, recursion, amazon-dynamodb

I've created a script to migrate data from Dynamo to a Mysql DB.
First I was not using Async, but I started getting bottlenecks on the sql side, so I decided to "throttle" the dymano part using the async lib.
The problem: I have a recursion in the middle of the path, as long as dynamo has data I have to continue the process (ultra simple ETL), but I don't know how to perform the recursion inside the waterfall.
My code :

```
function main() {
    async.waterfall([getMaxTimestamp, scanDynamoDB, printout, saveToMySQL], function(err, result) {
      if(err) console.log(err)
      console.log(result)
    });
}

function getMaxTimestamp(callback) {
    console.time("max query");
    connection.query("SELECT MAX(created_at) as start_date from Tracking;", function(err, data) {
        console.timeEnd("max query");
        callback(err, data);
    })
}

function scanDynamoDB(data, callback) {
    if (data[0].start_date != null && data[0].start_date)
        query.ExpressionAttributeValues[':v_ca'].N = data[0].start_date;

    console.time("dynamo read");
    dynamoDB.scan(query, function(err, data) {
        console.timeEnd("dynamo read");
        callback(err, data);
        // if (!err) {
        //     if (data != undefined && data.Count > 0) {
        //         printout(data.Items) // Print out the subset of results.
        //         if (data.LastEvaluatedKey) { // Result is incomplete; there is more to come.
        //             query.ExclusiveStartKey = data.LastEvaluatedKey;
        //             scanDynamoDB(query);
        //         }
        //     } else {
        //         console.log('No fresh data found on Dynamo')
        // } else console.dir(err);
    });
};

function assembleSql() {
    insertSql = "insert into Tracking (";
    for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
        insertSql += headers[i];
        if (i < headers.length - 1)
            insertSql += ",";
    }

    insertSql += ") values ?;"
    previousInsertSql = insertSql;
}

function saveToMySQL(items, callback) {
    assembleSql();
    //connection.connect();
    console.time("insert sql")
    connection.query(insertSql, [items], function(err, result) {
        console.timeEnd("insert sql")
        if (err){
          callback(err, null)
          return;
        }

        totalInserts += result.affectedRows;
        callback(err, totalInserts)
        //connection.end();
    })
}

function printout(items, callback) {
    var headersMap = {};
    var values;
    var header;
    var value;

    var out = [];

    if (headers.length == 0) {
        if (items.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                for (var key in items[i]) {
                    headersMap[key] = true;
                }
            }
        }
        for (var key in headersMap) {
            headers.push(key);
        }
    }

    for (index in items) {
        values = [];
        for (i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
            value = "";
            header = headers[i];
            // Loop through the header rows, adding values if they exist
            if (items[index].hasOwnProperty(header)) {
                if (items[index][header].N) {
                    value = items[index][header].N;
                } else if (items[index][header].S) {
                    value = items[index][header].S;
                } else if (items[index][header].SS) {
                    value = items[index][header].SS.toString();
                } else if (items[index][header].NS) {
                    value = items[index][header].NS.toString();
                } else if (items[index][header].B) {
                    value = items[index][header].B.toString('base64');
                } else if (items[index][header].M) {
                    value = JSON.stringify(items[index][header].M);
                } else if (items[index][header].L) {
                    value = JSON.stringify(items[index][header].L);
                } else if (items[index][header].BOOL !== undefined) {
                    value = items[index][header].BOOL.toString();
                }
            }
            values.push(value)
        }
        out.push(values)
    }
    callback(null, out);
}
main();
```

The commented part is where the recursion happens, but I don't know where to place this inside my flow !

Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I was able to figure it out by myself.

```
async.whilst(function() { return canInsert}, function (callback){
          scanDynamoDB(query, callback)
        }, function(err, res) {}
function scanDynamoDB(data, callback) {
    console.time("dynamo read");

    dynamoDB.scan(query, function(err, data) {
        console.timeEnd("dynamo read");
        if (!err) {
            if (data != undefined && data.Count > 0) {
                canInsert = data.LastEvaluatedKey;
                if (data.LastEvaluatedKey) // Result is incomplete; there is more to come.
                    query.ExclusiveStartKey = data.LastEvaluatedKey;
            }
        } else console.dir(err);
    });
};
```

I could have done it just with a `while(canInsert)`. Anyway, I avoided recursion and memory usage is way way lower.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't call callback function inside `scanDynamoDB` while fetching data. You can implement additional function and call it recursive while errors is not appears, like below

```
function scanDynamoDB(data, callback) {
    if (data[0].start_date != null && data[0].start_date)
        query.ExpressionAttributeValues[':v_ca'].N = data[0].start_date;

    console.time("dynamo read");

    var result = []; // for accumulate data of each query

    function readNext(err, data) {
        if (err)
            return callback(err);

        if (!data || !data.Count)   
            return callback(null, result);

        // add data to result   

        dynamoDB.scan(query, readNext);
    }

    dynamoDB.scan(query, readNext);
};
```

Comment: I may be wrong here, but by doing so, I will cut the waterfall chain, right ? I mean, once I have all the data read I'll continue to save to mysql, is that so ? And thank you for your help !

Comment: Yes, waterfall will wait all data. If you need process data by part then `readNext` must do it.

Comment: hmm how would that be then ? using readNext ? kinda new to async

Comment: Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: If your parts of data is independent then algorithm is: `getMaxTimestamp`  and do `async.parallel/each` for each value. It's common words because I don't understand clearly what you want and source-target mapping.

Comment: Ok, to make myself clear, from the scanDynamoDB I got back thousands of rows from the data callback, right ? Then, I have to insert this data into a SQL DB. After that, I check if dynamo has more data to fetch (`if (data.LastEvaluatedKey)`) and do that again and again, 'till I get no data left !

Comment: The main part of the algorithm is the "do I have more items ?" part and it's recursion. `if (data.LastEvaluatedKey) { // Result is incomplete; there is more to come.
                     query.ExclusiveStartKey = data.LastEvaluatedKey;
                     scanDynamoDB(query);
                 }`